# Is there any way to get master list of all apps through graph explorer API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

In **Azure Active Directory Admin Center**, I can see almost 200 application under **Enterprise Application**. How can I get this through **Microsoft graph Explorer**?

I tried with this: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications`, but it gave me the list of apps under **App Registration**.

**How can I get all the app list under enterprise application through graph explorer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Microsoft Graph API**

I'm sharing these first since you asked specifically about Microsoft Graph APIs in your question.

Please note that [List ServicePrincipals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-beta) api is only available under Beta endpoint.  **APIs in the beta endpoint are subject to change**. Microsoft does NOT recommend that you use them in your production apps. I've shared the alternative API's in the next section.

To get a complete list

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals
```

In case you need to filter down to only those where "Application Type" is "Enterprise Applications" like Azure portal allows (screenshot below)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$filter=tags/any(t:t eq 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp')
```

[image]

**Azure AD Graph API**

Even though in most cases it's advised to use the newer Microsoft Graph API, this particular case is such that Microsoft Graph API v1.0 doesn't support this functionality yet, so for production applications you should make use of Azure AD Graph API. Read here for more info [Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)

Complete List

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipals
```

Filtered down to only those where "Application Type" is "Enterprise Applications" like Azure portal allows

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/servicePrincipals?$filter=tags/any(t:t eq 'WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp')
```

---

On a side note, also consider using other query parameters like `$top` to get only say top 5 and `$select` to select only those fields which are really needed. Example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals?$select=appid,appDisplayName&$top=5
```