# How to get a list of app registrations in Azure tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get a list of app registrations in my Azure tenant.

I am using the tutorial found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2).
Also, I granted permission to my app per [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent).

I modified the sample app code as follows:

```
// Constants.cs
public const string ApplicationReadAll = "Application.Read.All";
```

Startup.cs:

```
// Added permission to read all applications
services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration, new string[] { Constants.ScopeUserRead, Constants.CalendarsReadWrite, Constants.ApplicationReadAll })
           .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

HomeController.cs:

```
// Get list of applications.
Graph::GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(new[] { Constants.ApplicationReadAll });
try
{
    var me = await graphClient.Applications.Request().GetAsync();
    ViewData["Me"] = me;

}
```

I have five apps registered in my tenant.  The response returns zero, as it does when I make the call from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).  I am logging in as Global Admin.

[image: a]

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591893/is-there-any-way-to-get-master-list-of-all-apps-through-graph-explorer-api).

Comment: I need you to provide two screenshots: 1. Go to azure portal->app registrations->all applications and provide the screenshot (here should be your 5 applications). 2. Provide a screenshot of you using Graph Explorer to call the API.

Comment: @CarlZhao thanks Carl  I'll do that as soon as I have a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I discovered:

`Directory.Read.All` permission is required.  `Application.Read.All` doesn't cut it.

The application (ClientID) that you use must have it's Supported account type set to "My organization only".

If necessary you can change this in the Manifest as follows:

```
 "signInAudience": "AzureADMyOrg",
```

Full credit and many thanks to [Mark Foppen](https://medium.com/@foppenm).  Read his [excellent blog post](https://medium.com/swlh/azure-ad-application-registration-security-with-graph-api-970625f977c7) and see his [code on github](https://github.com/foppenm/Microsoft-Graph-Applications).